# Ubuntu freezes when running program on many threads

Tags: 18.04, python

I have a new system and Ubuntu freezes whenever I run a program that spawns too many processes. (Frozen so that even holding Alt and the SysReq keys and typing REISUB does nothing, even though I activated them)

I have a python program that uses multiprocesses where an argument determines the number of processes to spawn. I have been using this without problem, spawning 24 processes on an Intel i7-8700k with 12 threads (on Ubuntu).

Now, I have a new Threadripper 2950X build (i.e. 16 cores / 32 threads) with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. When I run the program with more than ~20 processes, it freezes the whole machine and forces me to do a hard reset.

<s>However, I can start the program twice, (so 16 and 16 process) and it will run without a problem.</s>

**How do I find the problem? (I.e. narrow it down to python vs ubuntu vs hardware)**

I have looked at /var/log/syslog but nothing stands out (and I'm not sure what I'm looking for)

Photo of System Monitor on frozen screen:
[image]

Update:
The problem also happens when I run the program twice with 16 processes each
[image: htop output frozen]

Comment: Have you tried to nice it ? just for diagnostic.

Comment: I didn't know about nice! Running the program with `nice -n 19` has it running for the past 10 minutes while it used to crash within 20 seconds.  So the program was blocking the cpu because it had a priority that was too high? If you turn this into an answer I can accept it and if you know whether this behavior is a bug or a feature, please tell me!

Comment: My code writes and reads from file. I just move the working directory from an HDD to an SSD and now even with `nice -n 19` the program crashes. Is there any way to keep it from completely freezing the system and still use all computing resources?

Comment: I think part of the problem here is we don't know if this is a HW/SW problem.... I might suggest loading up a copy of Windows (you can use it for 30 days w/o activating) and seeing if the system freezes while running your program in Windows too.

Comment: @AndroidDev Good idea, I will need to check whether it will run on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a hardware issue.

I was able to reproduce the issue using this [test](https://github.com/suaefar/ryzen-test).

I am using the PRIME-X399-A motherboard. I noticed that there is a recently released bios update. Updating the bios resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use async concept in python. It is more efficient than threads. It used only one thread as a whole. For more details, refer https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

Comment: As the accepted answer notes, this was a hardware issue. Replacing processes with threads is useless here because of the python GIL